# c:forEach does not iterate all values

Tags: java, session, foreach, jstl

I have a arraylist tagged to a session, and when i try to iterate with `c:forEach`, it shows only first two class and there attributes, and when it comes to third class element in that arraylist, it just doesnt show values of attributes.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<table id="myTable"> 
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${jednaRez.stoRez.zauzetostStola == false || nema == true}"> 
            <tr>                          
                <td style="border: 0;"> 
                    <p style="font-size: 15px;">
                      &nbsp &nbspZauzetost stola: &nbsp <b>Slobodan </b> 
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:forEach items="${rezeSto}" var="rezSto">
                <tr>                          
                    <td style="border: 0;"> 
                        <p style="font-size: 15px;">
                          &nbsp &nbspZauzetost stola: &nbsp <b>Zauzet </b> 
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>                       
                <tr>                          
                    <td style="border: 0;"> 
                        <p style="font-size: 15px;">
                          &nbsp &nbspDatum rezervacije: &nbsp <b> <span id="datumRez">  ${rezSto.datumRezervacije} </span> </b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>                          
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        <p style="font-size: 15px;">
                           &nbsp &nbspTrajanje rezervacije: &nbsp <b> ${rezSto.rezervacijaTrajanje} </b> 
                        </p>
                    </td>                                 
                </tr>
                <tr>                          
                    <td style="border: 0;">
                        <p style="font-size: 15px;">
                           &nbsp &nbspKorisnici:<b> &nbsp ${rezSto.gost.korisnikIme} &nbsp ${rezSto.gost.korisnikPrezime} &nbsp </b><!--   <c:forEach items="${rezSto.pozvaniPrijatelji}" var="pri"> ,<b> ${pri.gost.korisnikIme} &nbsp ${pri.gost.korisnikPrezime}  </b> ,   </c:forEach>--> <br/>
                           ____________________________________________________________
                        </p>
                    </td>                                 
                </tr>
                <br/>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
</table>
```

Any ideas?

This is servlet where i create arrayList rezeSto:

```
Korisnik men = (Korisnik) request.getSession().getAttribute("menadzer");
    ArrayList<Rezervacija> sveRez = new ArrayList<Rezervacija>(rezervacijaDao.rezRestoran(men.getRestoran().getId()));
    ArrayList<Rezervacija> vazeceRez = null;
    try {
        vazeceRez = new ArrayList<Rezervacija>((List<Rezervacija>)men.vazeceRez(sveRez));
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<Rezervacija> rezStoIsti = new ArrayList<Rezervacija>();
    //samo one rezervacije koje sadrze poslati sto
    for(int i=0; i<vazeceRez.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vazeceRez.get(i).getStoRez().getId().equals(sifraStola))
        {
            rezStoIsti.add(vazeceRez.get(i));
        }
    }


    request.getSession().setAttribute("nema", false);
    if(rezStoIsti.size() == 0)
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("nema", true);
    }
    else
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("jednaRez", rezStoIsti.get(0));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("rezeSto", rezStoIsti);
    }



    request.getRequestDispatcher("stoPrikaz.jsp").forward(request, response);           
    return;
```

Comment: are you sure that you put in the sessionAttribute the list with right number elements

Comment: byr the way the code you commented a jstl block like this <!--   <c:forEach items="${rezSto.pozvaniPrijatelji}" var="pri"> ,<b> ${pri.gost.korisnikIme} &nbsp ${pri.gost.korisnikPrezime}  </b> ,   </c:forEach>--> this block will get executed .this is not how we commeent jstl expressions to comment it you should do this <%--   <c:forEach items="${rezSto.pozvaniPrijatelji}" var="pri"> ,<b> ${pri.gost.korisnikIme} &nbsp ${pri.gost.korisnikPrezime}  </b> ,   </c:forEach>--%>

Comment: achabahe YEAH MAN, that was the problem.Thx. :)

Answer (score 0):

If `c:forEach` prints first two and and you don not see the other list elements, i would suppose that when the second is got printed it breaks your html, that's why you don't see it, try to debug maybe really some special character gets printed out.

Comment: That class Rezervacija which is in that arrayList has another arrayList as atrribute.
And when that another list is empty, my code works.
But when its not empty, it only shows that Rezervacija which list is empty, and class which has some elements in her list doesnt show.
I dont know if that means anything.
But thx for reply.